# ¿Como puedo activar una funcion con diferentes acciones en un mismo botón mediante jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Lo que intento hacer es ejecutar diferentes acciones dentro de una función de jquery y que este método este vinculado siempre a un solo botón, cada vez que le des clic a ese mismo botón debe de aparecer una cosa diferente a a la anterior.

Codigo de jquery.

```
 function continuar1() {
    $("#imgselected").hide();

if ( $("#imgselected").css('display') == 'none' ) {
$("#captcha").show();
}


};
```

Ese código solo me funciona la primera vez, durante la primera rotación de pantalla, pero yo quiero rotar la pantalla un total de 4 veces con el mismo botón y que cada nuevo clic me de como resultado nueva información.

Answer (score 1):

Hice este script, tal vez no sea el mejor pero creo que cumple con el cometido

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Prueba</title>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function continuar1() {
    var random = Math.floor(Math.random()*4);
    for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        if (document.getElementsByTagName("img")[i].style.display == "block")document.getElementsByTagName("img")[i].style.display = "none";
    document.getElementsByTagName("img")[random].style.display = "block"; 
    }
    </script>
    <style type="text/css">
       img{display: none; width: 25%}
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <input type="button" onclick="continuar1()" value="presiona para captcha">
    <img src="http://www.chasecafe.org/images/captcha.png">
    <img src="https://c22blog.files.wordpress.com/2010/10/input-black.gif">
    <img src="https://www.abeautifulsite.net/content/uploads/2011/01/captcha.png">
    <img src="http://en.pureintegrity.eu/captcha-img.jpg">
  </body>
  </html>
```

Creo que Math.random() se basa en la hora actual entonces hay que esperar a que cambie, creo que un segundo, para que el captcha sea diferente, igual esto se puede modificar